# How to log in to laravel with MD5 and Bcrypt hashing at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hash, md5

I have a DataBase, the password store in it is hashing with MD5.

now I need to do some step:

1.User login(use bcrypt)

2.If(login failed)go to step3
  else loggin and exit

3.User login(use MD5)

4.If(login success){
update the hashing password in DataBase by bcrypt.
}

END

so my system need to check MD5 and bcrypt when loggin,

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that easily using your own authentication method as explained in the laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class YourCustomController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect('other/path');
        }

        $user = \App\Models\User::where([ // This model use your second connection to the other database
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => md5($request->password)
        ])->first();

        if ($user) {
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
            $user->save();

            $this->guard()->login($user);

            return redirect('other/path');;
        }

        return redirect('fail-path-with-instructions-for-create-account');

    }
}
```

I do recommend you also in your `routes/web.php` file create a named rout for to redirect to your new auth URL, this is because a lot of mechanisms build in laraver will automatcally redirect your user to the normal rout (like redirect if not logged in or if session expired).

```
Route::get('login', 'YourCustomController@login')->name('login');
```